# Bash - How to get the value of a specific element in an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array that is getting set correctly, and has the correct values and length when I print it out. However, when I do ${inputs[1]} to try and get a specific value it isn't returning anything.

Here's all the commands I'm using with my array (will try to simplify so I don't have to post my whole script):

```
# Instantiate, because I use it in a for loop (have also tried "declare -a inputs")
inputs=()

for (){
  # Get arguments into array
  inputs+=$1
  shift

  # do other stuff
}

# Test array has values
echo $inputs
# returns the arguments
echo ${#inputs}
# returns the # of arguments
echo ${inputs[0]}
# returns nothing, no matter what index
```

I feel like I'm going crazy, this is a very simple thing to do. At least I thought so. Couldn't find anything in documentation telling me to do anything different... so why isn't it bringing back a value?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code including (when it is re-run after fixing the bad use of `for`) the incorrect array usage.

Answer (score 2):

There is couple of things that you can change in your script to make it work. 
If you want to iterate through all arguments that were passed to your script, you can use simple for loop like this

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    # process current argument
done
```

Also you can add arguments to your `inputs` variable, but it probably should be done like this

```
inputs+=($arg)
```

First change is not so important, it's rather just a matter of preference, but second one should help you with your current problem.

Comment: More specifically: `inputs+=(something)` adds a new element to the array, but `inputs+=something` appends a string to the first element of the array (*not* a new element).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the echo from outside the function, while the values get assigned inside.

```
inputs=()

fored (){
  # Get arguments into array
  inputs+=$1
  shift

  # do other stuff
echo "${inputs[0]}"
}
```

Also, don't use "for" as function name.

Doing an execution(passing the value "pepito"):

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$ ./processing.sh 
pepito
```

BR

Comment: @pjh Copied what he had in his code and just changed the echo of the values so it would work, which was the problem he had. I stick on the topic and answer what is asked.